# Get closest point in collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to know how I can get the same result this function gives in Unity 2018.3 where it is not avaliable yet:

https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider2D.ClosestPoint.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem today, I'm also using 2018.3. Here's a helper function here that supplants collider2D.ClosestPoint. Edit the colliders as you need.

```
public static class Collider2DExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the closest point on a Collider2D relative to point
    /// </summary>
    public static Vector2 ClosestPoint(this Collider2D col, Vector2 point)
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject("tempCollider");
        go.transform.position = point;
        CircleCollider2D c = go.AddComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        c.radius = 0.1f;
        ColliderDistance2D dist = col.Distance(c);
        Object.Destroy(go);
        return dist.pointA;
    }
}
```

sourced it from this thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-closest-point-of-collider2d.225120/